# What technique should I use to create models and animation sequences in OpenGL code?

Tags: opengl, animation

I'm getting into game development using OpenGL (and the LWJGL library) and I want to create models for characters, NPC's etc. in the code, as well as animation sequences (for example the way the models are done in Minecraft).

What is the process to go about doing something like this? Is there a particular feature set that is used or common methods of doing this? I'm basically looking for pointers as to what to search for when trying to find examples of how this is done.

Comment: Character models are best done in modeling software such as Maya or 3DS Max.  Procedural modeling really only applies to terrain and environmental assets.  Procedural animation, however, has a lot of research available.  Often it's done using data stored by motion capture.  How crazy you want to get is up to you, as a lot of this stuff requires tons of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can start 3d modelling in http://www.blender.org/ ( Opensource. Or try 3dsmax if you have access. )
You can export as md2 / obj / etc. format, to import models and animations, in game.

Comment: I found the .x format to be particularly [nice for exporting](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/21515/7191) when doing animation with Blender.